# jq select and contains error: null (null) and string ("randomtext1") cannot have their containment checked

Tags: select, jq, containment

command:

```
cat test.json | jq -r '.[] | select(.["$link"] | contains("randomtext1")).id'
```

I was expecting to have both ids (a and b) show up as result of the above command since they both contains `"randomtext1"` text under

```
"input"|"obj1"|"$link" and "input"|"obj3"|"$link".
```

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:11): null (null) and string ("randomtext1") cannot have their containment checked
parse error: Expected value before ',' at line 11, column 2
```

I see that the `"$link"` object is within the `"input"` and `"obj#"` objects. How do I specify them or do I need to? The error message seems to be pointing to something else. Also only the `"input"` and `"$link"` are constant among the records, the name of the `"obj#"` can change which makes them random.

The test.json file:

```
[{
      "input": {
            "obj1": {
                "$link": "randomtext1"
            }, 
            "obj2": {
                "$link": "randomtext2"
            }
      },
      "id": "a"
},
{
      "input": {
            "obj3": {
                "$link": "randomtext1"
            }, 
            "obj4": {
                "$link": "randomtext3"
            }
      },
      "id": "b"
}]
```

Comment: Thanks @peak. Fixed by adding square brackets at the beginning and the end of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter:

```
.[]
| select(.input[] | .["$link"] | contains("randomtext1")) 
| .id
```

produces:

```
"a"
"b"
```

Note, however, that `contains` has very complex semantics, so it would probably be better to use `index` instead.